# Drawing a trawling boat with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to draw a diagram of a boat with LaTeX and I have started using a package called TikZ which looks very promising but I'm not sure how to use it to draw diagrams other than rectangles and other basic shapes. Would someone be able to guide me through the process of drawing a boat with TikZ? The diagram I had in mind was

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.sx! Please see [Draw an aircraft with Tikz](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/114783). While this is possible with TikZ it is very tedious. Can’t you simply include this image (best in vector format) via `\includegraphics` or create it in Inkscape or similar software?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about "Just do it for me". On this site, a question should typically revolve around an abstract issue (e.g. "How do I get a double horizontal line in a table?") rather than a concrete application (e.g. "How do I make this table?"). Please try to make your question clear and simple by giving a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228): you'll stand a greater chance of getting help.

Comment: You might want to look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/114783/draw-an-aircraft-with-tikz