# Drawing figure of a boat with the Tikz-package

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, tikz-external, tikz-arrows

I want to draw a simple figure of a boat in LaTex, does anyone know a good way to do that? Is TikZ the best package to use for this? I want it to look similar to the boat in the picture below, which I think seem to have been made using TikZ. Any ideas on how to accomplish this?
[image: Simple picture of a boat]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Yes, TikZ is great for this. I suggest splitting the task of drawing into smaller tasks, look at the TikZ manual to see how each one can be done. If there's a specific problem which a part of the drawing, look at the existing TikZ questions here to find an already existing answer or post a question regarding that specific problem. That's efficient, one can learn, we add solutions to the database here, while a "please draw a complete thing" for me would be different, possibly this is not meant.

Comment: That drawing doesn't understand what perspective is. Why don't you find a proper one at least to copy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sub>A boat! Couldn't resist.</sub>

This should get you started.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=4mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.5cm,y=0.5cm,thick,line cap=round]
    \draw (0,4) -- (4,0) -- +(0,-2);
    \draw (4,-2) to[out=180,in=-90,looseness=1.2] (0,4);
    \draw (0,4) to [out=50,in=190,looseness=0.8] (14,14);
    \draw (4,0) to [out=40,in=260,looseness=0.8] (14,14);
    \draw (4,-2) to [out=40,in=280,looseness=0.8] (14,14);
    \draw[name path=a,line width=1pt, -latex] (0,0) -- (16,16)
                            node[pos=0.9,inner sep=3mm] (x) {}
                            node[pos=1.02] {$x_b$};
    \draw[name path=b,line width=1pt, -latex] (0,14) -- (14,0) node[pos=1.02] {$y_b$};
    \path[name intersections={of=a and b,by={I}}];
    \draw[line width=1pt,dashed, -latex] (I)node[right,font=\tiny] {CoG} -- +(0,-5cm)
                            node[pos=1.02] {$z_b$};
    \draw[-latex] (x.north west) to[out=110,in=-20,looseness=5] (x.south east);
    \node[right,font=\tiny] at ([xshift=5mm]x.east) {roll $p$};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It's OK, but it is not as good as this [aircraft](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/114783/draw-an-aircraft-with-tikz/114847#114847)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: But my boat can float! :P

Comment: Beware, I may increase `$p$`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Then I shall name it *Titanic* :)