# Does any have a compilable .dtx file which contain some metafont words to creat one character?

Tags: fonts, packages

I found it's difficult to download a compilable .dtx from CTAN. I want yo use .dtx to develop some package containing some simple character not only the macros as an exercise of my latex programming.

Comment: Imho a font package isn't the best first project. Fonts are quite complicated beasts in tex.

Comment: Thanks. In the past, I am a mathematical user of Latex, but now the task for my work require me to design new symbol such as the hieroglf did.

Comment: But why with metafont? Drawing it with tikz would be easier. Or look here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/413073/creating-custom-mathematical-symbols/413085#413085

Comment: You don't have to use a `.dtx` at all: first try simply solving the problem you are targetting. (Indeed, fonts don't tend to be in `.dtx` format, which is aimed at LaTeX package code.)

Comment: You should be aware of an important limitation of bitmap fonts: they don't scale. If you use metafont and do not afterwards convert your font, it will not be suitable for use in electronic documents as it won't scale. In contrast, if you create a type1 font in FontForge or use Ti*k*Z or similar, it will be.

Comment: Thanks all of your anwsers. The potential reason of my question is that it's not easy to get font editor for me, and there also is lack of oppotunity to trian this for me.

Comment: FontForge is an amazing software to read the pfb files, but how can I use the FontForge to develop myself font package?