Triangle with bold (thicker) vertical part
I need a triangle symbol for which the < part is normal font and the | part is bold (or thicker) font. I found \lhd and \triangle but thus far no variant with the above property. Do you know of such a symbol in latex?

Are you looking for a form of uppercase Delta, like $\Delta$ or \usepackage{upgreek}...$\Updelta$? Both symbols have a thicker side to the right. These two are the symbols you find at https://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html . Otherwise you probably have to design it with tikz, metafont, pstricks etc.

does it have to be bold, as I don't think that is in Unicode but Unicode does have a triangle operator with a double struck right bar U+29CF ⧏

https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/413073/creating-custom-mathematical-symbols may help (picture mode ;-)!)

As a quick hack, you could combine an existing triangle with a rule so one sides appears thicker:
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}

\begin{document}

$\triangleleft\kern-0.1ex\rule[-0.01ex]{0.15ex}{1.19ex}$

\end{document}



As it currently stands this is not something which is doable, a technical (albeit not great looking in my opinion) workaround is using tikz to manually draw the character, and introduce it as a command.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz} % For drawing custom symbols

\newcommand{\customtriangle}{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.2,baseline=0]
        % Draw the normal left part of the triangle
        \draw[thin] (0,0) -- (1,2) -- (2,0);
        % Draw the bold right vertical part of the triangle
        \draw[very thick] (2,0) -- (2,2);
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}

Here is your custom triangle symbol: $\customtriangle$

\end{document}

Hope this helps.

The thicker segment was supposed to be a side of the triangle.
