# Creating IKEA-style instructions in LaTeX

Tags: book-design

**Edit:** Fixed a typo, added an example picture.

Dear TeX-ers. I really like the visual style of IKEA instructions, see below for an example, and I have sometimes played with the idea of making same type of manuals to explain some mathematical concepts. A few months ago I came across a story describing how some group of physicists(?) had used an IKEA style description to explain their ideas. (It wasn't the IKEA instruction to LHC, but something more serious.) I don't remember if they used LaTeX, but I lost the source and my memories are too vague to find it again. Thus the question:

> Are there any existing LaTeX styles that would be suitable to create IKEA-style manuals?

I guess something like Inkscape might be more suitable for these types of projects, but I don't know how to use that and, more importantly, if something is worth doing it is worth doing it in LaTeX.

[image: IKEA example]

Comment: You can use LaTeX to make toast, but it really isn't the best way to do it. You can have a look at Ti*k*Z, PSTricks, Metapost or Asymptote, but i don't think any of them is the right tool to do the job.

Comment: Are there any examples online for people who have never seen an ikea manual?

Comment: http://tex-talk.net/2012/10/i-tex-therefore-i-toast/

Comment: @DavidCarlisle If i remember correctly, the people in the instruction do look like you would have painted them with MS Paint. No offense, they really look like that.

Comment: @Johannes_B [can you buy aircraft at these shops?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/114783/draw-an-aircraft-with-tikz/114847#114847)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle No idea, i heard they have everything. Have been to IKEA only three times in my life.

Comment: Of course, IKEA is highly mathematical ... http://loopspace.mathforge.org/CountingOnMyFingers/Ikea/

Comment: related site: https://idea-instructions.com/

Comment: @LoopSpace This is brilliant!

Comment: The neat alignments and the style shown can definitely be done with LaTeX, but I would not recommend that you draw these diagrams with LaTeX, even if you already have a package to support that.

Comment: If I had more motivation, I would provide a baffling answer using pictographs.

Comment: The `IKEA instruction for the LHC` ... that would be nice ;-) IKEA is an acronym for `incredible kinkily engineered accelerators` ;-)

Comment: I would split up two things here. One is the clearly 3D CAD exported drawings and then the overall layout. While I think it does not make sense to draw all of the 3D CAD parts by hand with TikZ, everything else could be done very easily.