# How to draw a diagram with arrows?

Tags: diagrams, arrows, draw

[image]

I want to draw the following diagram in LaTeX:

[image]

Comment: You could youre the TikZ package,  you will find a short tutorial at the begin of the documentation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's quite easy with `tikz-cd`:

> [image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
1 \ar[r,"a"] \ar[rr,bend right,"c"'] & 2 \ar[r,"b"] & 3
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

But, in my humble opinion, I'd vote for [picture-mode](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/45267628#45267628), for its *far* more user-friendly syntax:

> [image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pict2e}
\begin{document}
\setlength{\unitlength}{1cm}
\begin{picture}(2.1,0.75)(0,-0.45)
\put(0,0){1}
  \put(0.2,0.1){\vector(1,0){0.75}}
  \put(0.5,0.15){\footnotesize$a$}
\put(1,0){2}
  \put(1.2,0.1){\vector(1,0){0.75}}
  \put(1.5,0.15){\footnotesize$b$}
\put(2,0){3}
  \qbezier(0.2,-0.05)(1.05,-0.7)(1.9,-0.05)
  \put(1.9,-0.05){\vector(4,3){0.0001}}
  \put(1.0,-0.55){\footnotesize$c$}
\end{picture}
\end{document}
```

---

Update: `tikz-cd` solution for the second diagram:

> [image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
  1 \ar[r,"a_1"]
    \ar[rrrrr,bend right=50,looseness=0.3,"b"']
& 2 \ar[r,"a_2"]
& 3 \ar[r,"a_3"]
& \cdots
  \ar[r,"a_{n-2}"] % This arrow isn't in the picture, but I chose to add it. Feel free to remove.
& n-1 \ar[r,"a_{n-1}"]
& n
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Actually, it's also very easy with plain TikZ (without tikz-cd), but +1 for picture mode ;)

Comment: @TeXnician The `tikz-cd` answer is so that people can't say I posted a picture mode answer just to gain more rep. [I honestly don't know why people think that](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/114847/134574) ;P

Comment: Your first suggestion is very practical but when I get n points (1, 2, 3, ..., n-1, n)  I could not print a_1, a_2,...a_{n-1} on each arrow and I couldn't print b on 
 below arrow from 1 to n. Can you help me?

Comment: @FatmaErolKaynarca The first method can certainly be adapted to do what you want. Can you please upload a picture of what you want, I couldn't understand from your description.

Comment: Okay, I am sorry:( I made correction in the first part I asked the question, can you see from there? If you don't see I upload a picture again, thank you:)

Comment: @FatmaErolKaynarca I updated my answer with a diagram similar to the one you uploaded.

Comment: @FatmaErolKaynarca You're welcome :)

Answer (score 12):

For the sake of completeness, here it is a plain TikZ approach

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 2cm, thick]% 
        \node (1) {1};
        \node (2) [right=of 1] {2};
        \node (3) [right=of 2] {3};
        \draw[->] (1) -- node [midway,above] {a} (2);
        \draw[->] (1) to [bend right] node [midway,below]{c} (3);
        \draw[->] (2) -- node [midway,above] {b} (3);
    \end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

### [image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 2cm, thick]% 
        \node (1) {1};
        \node (2) [right=of 1] {2};
        \node (3) [right=of 2] {3};
        \node (dots) [right=of 3] {$\cdots$};
        \node (n1) [right=of dots] {$n-1$};
        \node (n) [right=of n1] {$n$};
        %
        \draw[->] (1) -- node [midway,above] {$a_1$} (2);
        \draw[->] (1) to [bend right=15cm] node [midway,below]{b} (n);
        \draw[->] (2) -- node [midway,above] {$a_2$} (3);
        \draw[->] (3) -- node [midway,above] {$a_3$} (dots);
        \draw[->] (dots) -- node [midway,above] {$a_{n-2}$} (n1);
        \draw[->] (n1) -- node [midway,above] {$a_{n-1}$} (n);
    \end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I can't print letters indexed on arrows ?

Comment: @FatmaErolKaynarca could you explain more? Doesn't my code work with you?

Comment: Your typed code works very well, but I wanted to do something else, I couldn't fit what I wanted to do with your code.

Comment: @FatmaErolKaynarca does my answer update get what you want?

Comment: @FatmaErolKaynarca if you mean you can't type, for example, `a` with subscript `1`, you have to type this inside inline math mode by embracing it with the double dollar signs `$a_1$`.

Comment: @FatmaErolKaynarca You are most welcome.

Answer (score 5):

A `pstricks`solution: the three numbers are defined as nodes, and we link them by node connections.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pst-node, auto-pst-pdf}

\begin{document}

\[
  \Rnode{1}{1} \hspace{3em} \Rnode{2}{2} \hspace{3em} \Rnode{3}{3}
\psset{linewidth=0.6pt, arrows=->, arrowinset=0.12, nodesep=0.6ex, labelsep=2pt, shortput=nab}
\everypsbox{\scriptstyle}
\ncline{1}{2}^{a}\ncline{2}{3}^{b}
\ncarc[arcangle=-30]{1}{3}_{c}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

With Ti*k*Z, it is possible to use the `chain` concept of the `graphs` library.

`chains` are a series of `nodes` whose syntax is abbreviated compared to their normal syntax. A chain ends with a semicolon. The nodes and their text are identical by default as in the first figure. Nodes and text are the number `1`, `2` and `3`.

This first figure is composed of 2 chains: the first `1->2->3` and the second which goes directly from 1 to 3.

To add text to the arrow (that is called edge by tikz), simply place the option `edge label` or `edge label'` depending on whether the text is above or below the arrow.  In reality, this places the text to the **left** or **right** when walking in the direction of the chain.

In the second example, to avoid having to draw an arrow, we write `-!-` instead of `->` *(see section `19.3.3 Syntax of Chain Specifications` page 272 of 3.1.1 TikZ manual)*.
To make the `node text` different from its name, simply separate the name from the text with a slash. For example : `5/{$n-1$}` means that node `5` displays the `n-1` text.

#### With the `quotes` library:

Using the `quotes` library, the syntax for writing labels is even shorter:
`"a"` instead of `edge label={a}`
`"c"'` instead of `edge label' ={c}`
You can customize the colors as below:

[image: chaine]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs,quotes}
\begin{document}

\tikz[thick,gray] \graph[grow right=30mm] {
1 ->["a"] 2   ->["b"] 3;
1 -> [bend right,"c"'] 3;
};

General case:
\smallskip

\tikz[thick,every edge/.style={red,draw},every node/.style={blue}] \graph[grow right=20mm,edge quotes={black,auto}] {
1 ->["$a_1$"] 2   ->["$a_2$"] 3->["$a_3$"] 4/$\cdots$   -!- 5/{$n-1$}->["$a_{n-1}$"] n  ;
1 -> [bend right,"b"'] n;
};

\end{document}
```

#### Without the `quotes` library

[image: chaine-tikz]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}
\begin{document}

\tikz \graph[grow right=30mm] {
1 ->[edge label={a}] 2   ->[edge label={b}] 3;
1 -> [bend right,edge label'={c}] 3;
};


\tikz \graph[grow right=20mm] {
1 ->[edge label={$a_1$}] 2   ->[edge label={$a_2$}] 3->[edge label={$a_3$}] 4/$\cdots$   -!- 5/{$n-1$}->[edge label={$a_{n-1}$}] n  ;
1 -> [bend right,edge label'={b}] n;
};

\end{document}
```

Translated with www.DeepL.com/Translator