# Chalenge in tikz

Tags: tikz-arrows, tikz-pic, tikz-angles

I'm working on a aerodynamic proyect and i have to do something like this in the report.

[image]

I'm just interesed in the vectors, not in the airplane. How can I do to make a tikz picture to be as similar as that image?

Regards

Comment: Of course your project will top all others if you [draw the plane](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/114847/134574) too :D

Comment: Yeah! I know, but I have already the airfoil (I made it with tikz too). So I just replace the airplane with the airfoil.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{angles,quotes,arrows.meta} 
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>={Stealth[length=7pt]},fine dots/.style={dash pattern=on 0.8pt off 0.8pt}]
\draw[line width=2pt,gray,-{Stealth[length=10pt,black]}]
 (0,0) coordinate (O) -- (-10:1.5) node[midway,below,black]{$V$};
\draw[fine dots,->]  (O) -- (15:4) node[near
end,above] {$OX_a$} coordinate (p1);
\draw[densely dashed,<->] (-10:4)  coordinate (p2) -- (O)
node[near start,below] {$OX_w$} -- (0:4)  coordinate (p3);
\draw[densely dashed,<->] (-90:4)  coordinate (p4) -- (O) -- (-100:4) 
node[near end,left] {$OZ_w$} coordinate (p5);
\draw[>={Stealth[length=4pt]}] pic["$\alpha$" anchor=north east, draw,<-, angle eccentricity=0.95,angle radius=3cm,fine dots] {angle=p2--O--p1}
pic["$\theta$" anchor=west, draw,<-, angle eccentricity=1.02,angle radius=3.5cm,fine dots] {angle=p3--O--p1}
pic["$\gamma$" anchor=west, draw,->, angle eccentricity=1.02,angle
radius=3.5cm,fine dots] {angle=p2--O--p3};
\draw[-{Stealth[length=8pt]}] (-30:2) arc(-30:-170:2) node[pos=1,right=2pt]{$+$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's perfect! Great work! Thank you so much :)