# Insert Plane symbol

Tags: symbols

From this document [Comprehensive symbols](http://tug.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf) I see there is a `bbding` plane symbol which can be inserted into LaTeX. As a newbie to LaTeX, would you mind helping me understand how to insert it? The following attempts haven’t worked:

- `\Plane`
- `\textplane`
- `\equation{\plane}`
- `$\plane$`

[image]

Comment: You might not know this page: http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html. Use it to find all the symbols you would like to add as well as the package you will need to import in order to use it.

Comment: And then there's https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/114847/134574

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should load the package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bbding}
\begin{document}
\Plane
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this. I thought That I had tried this, but actually I hadn’t.

Answer (score 4):

My answer peraphs it is off-topic with your request to use `bbding` package. One day could use also an airplane departing or arriving (2nd and 3nd icon) with `fontawesome5` package which contains all the icons from the Twitter Bootstrap framework, and now many more.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontawesome5}

\begin{document}
\faPlane, \quad \faPlaneArrival, \quad 
\faPlaneDeparture
\end{document}
```

Comment: The second one looks more like it's crashing.  That's not the attitude in which planes land.