# Convert TikZ code to `picture` environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, tikz-graphdrawing, picture-mode

I created two figures using Ti*k*Z, they appear below. Now, the document doesn't compile in Scientific Workplace 5.5, it seems that it has issues with Ti*k*Z.

In SWP5.5 the picture environment works well so I want to re-create those figures using that environment but I have no idea how to proceed.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsfonts,amsmath}
\usepackage{color,graphicx}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,svgnames,x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz,pgfplots,pgfkeys}
\usetikzlibrary{%
    arrows,
    arrows.meta,
    cd,
    matrix,
    decorations.pathreplacing,
    positioning,
    calc,
    fit,
    shapes,
    shapes.symbols,
    shapes.multipart,%rectangle split
    shapes.arrows,
    backgrounds,
    snakes,
    shadows.blur,
    trees,%for probability trees
    shadows,% drop shadows
    fadings
}
\usepackage{adjustbox,float}

\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{10}

\textheight 18cm
\textwidth 12cm
\oddsidemargin +3cm
\evensidemargin +1cm
%\input{tcilatex}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
%   \tikzstyle{black circle}=[draw,circle, fill=black, inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt, minimum size=5pt]
    \begin{adjustbox}{max width=0.85\textwidth} 
        \begin{tikzpicture}[%
        %transform canvas={scale=1,shift={(0cm,0cm)}},
        tbox/.style={rectangle,draw,line width=1.2pt},%
        box/.style args={#1 x #2}{tbox,minimum width=#1,minimum height=#2},%
        node distance=0.2em,%
        >=stealth,%
        every text node part/.style={%
            align=center,%
            font=\tiny},%
        ]
        \node (n1) [] at (10.1,29.0) {};
        \node (n2) [] at (11.0,10.0) {};
        \node (n3) [] at (0.4,20) {};
        \node (n4) [] at (19,19) {};
        \node (n5) [] at (0.7,22.7) {};
        \node (n6) [] at (20,11) {};
        \node (n7) [] at (6.8,28.35) {};
        \node (n8) [] at (18.5,9.35) {};
        \node (n9) [] at (1.05,16.8) {};
        \node (n10) [] at (19.5,28) {};
        \node (n11) [] at (7.10,10.7) {};
        \node (n12) [] at (18,29) {};
        \node (t1) [label={\large 4213}] at (8.5,27.5) {};
        \node (t2) [label={[text depth=-5ex, rotate=-60]right:\large (24)13}] at (8,27) {};
        \node (t3) [label={[text depth=1ex, rotate=95]left:\large 4(12)3}] at (9.85,28) {};
        \node (t4) [label={\large 4123}] at (13,26.5) {};
        \node (t5) [label={[text depth=1ex, rotate=65]left:\large 41(23)}] at (17.25,28.5) {};
        \node (t6) [label={\large 4132}] at (18.5,27.7) {};
        \node (t7) [label={[text depth=1ex, rotate=30]right:\large (14)32}] at (17.95,26.5) {};
        \node (ah1) [] at (16.25,25.9) {};
        \node (at1) [] at (18,25.71) {};
        \node (t8) [label={right: \large (14)(23)}] at (18.15,25.65) {};
        \node (t9) [label={\large 2413}] at (5.15,24) {};
        \node (t10) [label={\large 1423}] at (16.4,22) {};
        \node (t11) [label={\large (124)3}] at (8.65,22.25) {};
        \node (at2) [] at (9.3,22.7) {};
        \node (ah2) [] at (10.33, 22.53) {};
        \node (t12) [label={\large 2431}] at (0.9,20.8) {};
        \node (t13) [label={\large 2(34)1}] at (1.62,19.8) {};
        \node (t14) [label={\large 2341}] at (1.60,18.45) {};
        \node (t15) [label={[text depth=1ex, rotate=-30]right:\large 24(13)}] at (1.45,21.7) {};
        \node (t16) [label={[text depth=1ex, rotate=30]right:\large 23(14)}] at (1.8,16.85) {};
        \node (t17) [label={\large 2314}] at (5.1,15.18) {};
        \node (t18) [label={\large 2(134)}] at (6.3,17.75) {};
        \node (ah3) [] at (5.73,19.73) {};
        \node (at3) [] at (5.73,18.53) {};
        \node (t19) [label={[text depth=1ex, rotate=-30]right:\large 2(13)4}] at (7.42,18.05) {};
        \node (t20) [label={[text depth=1ex, rotate=60]right:\large (23)14}] at (7.47,12) {};
        \node (t21) [label={\large 3214}] at (8.9,11.42) {};
        \node (t22) [label={\large (123)4}] at (8.85,16.1) {};  
        \node (ah4) [] at (10.6,16.66) {};
        \node (at4) [] at (9.5,16.6) {};
        \node (t23) [label={[text depth=1ex, rotate=95]right:\large 3(12)4}] at (10.55,10.94) {};
        \node (t24) [label={\large 3124}] at (13.24,11.52) {};
        \node (t25) [label={\large (13)(24)}] at (14.3,12.5) {};
        \node (ah5) [] at (16,13.55) {};
        \node (at5) [] at (15,12.95) {};
        \node (t26) [label={[text depth=1ex, rotate=-30]right:\large (13)24}] at (12,15.25) {};
        \node (t27) [label={\large 3142}] at (18.8,10) {};
        \node (t28) [label={[text depth=1ex, rotate=-35]right:\large (13)42}] at (17.7,12) {};
        \node (t29) [label={[text depth=1ex, rotate=-55]right:\large 31(24)}] at (17.2,11.8) {};
        \node (t30) [label={[text depth=1ex, rotate=-55]right:\large 13(24)}] at (13.87,17.40) {};
        \node (t31) [label={\large 1324}] at (12.13,17) {};
        \node (t32) [label={\large 1342}] at (15.83,16.87) {};
        \node (t33) [label={\large 1(234)}] at (14.25,19.25) {};
        \node (t34) [label={\large 1(34)2}] at (16.75,19) {};
        \node (ah6) [] at (12.25,19.43) {};
        \node (at6) [] at (13.65,19.7) {};
        \node (t35) [label={\large 1423}] at (12.3,21.75) {};
        \node (t36) [label={[text depth=1ex, rotate=35]right:\large (14)23}] at (12.13,23) {};
        \node (t37) [label={[text depth=1ex, rotate=-55]right:\large 1(24)3}] at (11.18,21.5) {};
        \node (t38) [label={[text depth=1ex, rotate=59]right:\large 14(23)}] at (13.13,21.65) {};
        \node (t40) [label={\large 1243}] at (11.12,19.95) {};
        \node (t41) [label={\large 12(34)}] at (11.3,19.3) {};
        \node (t42) [label={\large 1234}] at (11.23,18.7) {};
        \node (t43) [label={[text depth=1ex, rotate=60]right:\large 1(23)4}] at (10.85,17.6) {};
        \node (t44) [label={\large 2143}] at (8.7,19.95) {};
        \node (t45) [label={\large 21(34)}] at (8.37,19.35) {};
        \node (t46) [label={[text depth=1ex, rotate=30]right:\large 2(14)3}] at (7.53,20.4) {};
        \node (t47) [label={[text depth=1ex, rotate=93]right:\large (12)43}] at (10.17,19.85) {};
        \node (t48) [label={[text depth=3ex, rotate=93]right:\large (12)34}] at (10.38,17.5) {};
        \node (t49) [label={\large (12)(34)}] at (8.75,18.5) {};
        \node (t50) [label={\large 2134}] at (9.06,18) {};
        \node (ah7) [] at (10.6,19.35) {};
        \node (at7) [] at (9.4,19) {};

%       
%       %%%==================================================================
%       
        \draw [-, line width=3pt] (n1)  -- (n2);
        \draw [-, line width=3pt] (n3)  -- (n4);
        \draw [-, line width=3pt] (n5)  -- (n6);
        \draw [-, line width=3pt] (n7)  -- (n8);
        \draw [-, line width=3pt] (n9)  -- (n10);
        \draw [-, line width=3pt] (n11)  -- (n12);
        \draw [->, line width=1.5pt] (at1)  -- (ah1);
        \draw [->, line width=1.5pt] (at2)  -- (ah2);
        \draw [->, line width=1.5pt] (at3)  -- (ah3);
        \draw [->, line width=1.5pt] (at4)  -- (ah4);
        \draw [->, line width=1.5pt] (at5)  -- (ah5);
        \draw [->, line width=1.5pt] (at6)  -- (ah6);
        \draw [->, line width=1.5pt] (at7)  -- (ah7);

        \end{tikzpicture}   
    \end{adjustbox}
    \begin{picture}(120,15)  
    \put(60,0){\makebox(0,0)[b]{Figure 2.3}}    
    \end{picture}
\end{figure}

\clearpage

\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \tikzstyle{black circle}=[draw,circle, fill=black, inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt, minimum size=5pt]
    \begin{adjustbox}{max width=0.75\textwidth} 
    \begin{tikzpicture}[%
    %transform canvas={scale=1,shift={(0cm,0cm)}},
    tbox/.style={rectangle,draw,line width=1.2pt},%
    box/.style args={#1 x #2}{tbox,minimum width=#1,minimum height=#2},%
    node distance=0.2em,%
    >=stealth,%
    every text node part/.style={%
        align=center,%
        font=\tiny},%
    ]
    \node (n1) [black circle, label=above:{\Large 2134}] at (7.4,26.8) {};
    \node (n2) [black circle, label=above:{\Large 1234}] at (10.4,27.24) {};
    \node (n3) [black circle, label=above:{\Large 1243}] at (14,26) {};
    \node (n4) [black circle, label=below right:{\Large 2143}] at (11.05,25.65) {};
    \node (n5) [black circle, label=above left:{\Large 1324}] at (9.6,24.6) {};
    \node (n6) [black circle, label=below right:{\Large 2314}] at (3.32,23.75) {};
    \node (n7) [black circle, label=above left:{\Large 3214}] at (2.6,21.10) {};
%   \node (n8) [black circle, label={[xshift=1.0cm, yshift=-.5cm]\Large 3124}] at (5.65,21.55) {};
    \node (n8) [black circle, label={[label distance=0.5cm]0:\Large 3124}] at (5.65,21.55) {};
    \node (n9) [black circle, label=above left:{\Large 2413}] at (10.85,21.35) {};
    \node (n10) [black circle, label=above right:{\Large 1342}] at (12.55,20.8) {};
    \node (n11) [black circle, label=right:{\Large 1423}] at (17.10,22.15) {};
    \node (n12) [black circle, label=above right:{\Large 2341}] at (3.2,19.45) {};
    \node (n13) [black circle, label=below left:{\Large 1432}] at (16.3,19.55) {};
    \node (n14) [black circle, label=below left:{\Large 2431}] at (7,18.4) {};
    \node (n15) [black circle, label=below right:{\Large 3142}] at (8.65,17.75) {};
    \node (n16) [black circle, label=below right:{\Large 4213}] at (13.75,17.55) {};
    \node (n17) [black circle, label=right:{\Large 4123}] at (16.95,17.95) {};
    \node (n18) [black circle, label=right:{\Large 3241}] at (2.5,16.9) {};
    \node (n19) [black circle, label=left:{\Large 4231}] at (9.9,14.5) {};
    \node (n20) [black circle, label=left:{\Large 4132}] at (16.2,15.4) {};
    \node (n21) [black circle, label=left:{\Large 3421}] at (5.35,13) {};
    \node (n22) [black circle, label=above left:{\Large 3412}] at (8.5,13.5) {};
    \node (n23) [black circle, label=below:{\Large 4321}] at (9.10,11.95) {};
    \node (n24) [black circle, label=below right:{\Large 4312}] at (12.2,12.25) {};

    %%%==================================================================

    \draw [-, line width=3pt] (n1)  -- (n2);
    \draw [-, line width=3pt] (n2)  -- (n3);
    \draw [-, line width=3pt] (n1)  -- (n4);
    \draw [-, line width=3pt] (n4)  -- (n3);
    \draw [-, line width=3pt] (n6)  -- (n1);
    \draw [-, line width=3pt] (n7)  -- (n6);
    \draw [-, line width=3pt] (n6)  -- (n12);
    \draw [-, line width=3pt] (n12)  -- (n14);
    \draw [-, line width=3pt] (n14)  -- (n9);
    \draw [-, line width=3pt] (n9)  -- (n4);
    \draw [-, line width=3pt] (n16)  -- (n9);
    \draw [-, line width=3pt] (n16)  -- (n17);
    \draw [-, line width=3pt] (n17)  -- (n11);
    \draw [-, line width=3pt] (n11)  -- (n3);
    \draw [-, line width=3pt] (n7)  -- (n18);
    \draw [-, line width=3pt] (n12)  -- (n18);
    \draw [-, line width=3pt] (n14)  -- (n19);
    \draw [-, line width=3pt] (n19)  -- (n16);
    \draw [-, line width=3pt] (n18)  -- (n21);
    \draw [-, line width=3pt] (n21)  -- (n23);
    \draw [-, line width=3pt] (n23)  -- (n24);
    \draw [-, line width=3pt] (n24)  -- (n20);
    \draw [-, line width=3pt] (n20)  -- (n17);
    \draw [-, line width=3pt] (n19)  -- (n23);
    \draw [-, dotted, line width=2pt] (n2)  -- (n5);
    \draw [-, dotted, line width=2pt] (n7)  -- (n8);
    \draw [-, dotted, line width=2pt] (n5)  -- (n8);
    \draw [-, dotted, line width=2pt] (n8)  -- (n15);
    \draw [-, dotted, line width=2pt] (n15)  -- (n10);
    \draw [-, dotted, line width=2pt] (n10)  -- (n5);
    \draw [-, dotted, line width=2pt] (n10)  -- (n13);
    \draw [-, dotted, line width=2pt] (n13)  -- (n11);
    \draw [-, dotted, line width=2pt] (n15)  -- (n22);
    \draw [-, dotted, line width=2pt] (n21)  -- (n22);
    \draw [-, dotted, line width=2pt] (n22)  -- (n24);
    \draw [-, dotted, line width=2pt] (n13)  -- (n20);
    \end{tikzpicture}   
    \end{adjustbox}
    \begin{picture}(120,15)  
    \put(60,0){\makebox(0,0)[b]{Figure 2.6}}    
    \end{picture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The `picture` environment is very simple and allows only a few basic operations ([this airplane](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/114847/) is a (locally) famous example). Converting a TikZ image to picture mode is therefore not really possible. Maybe you can use a different compiler, or try to get TikZ to work in SW (maybe https://www.sciword.co.uk/mailings/May2016.htm can be helpful?)

Comment: @Marijn don't you like my plane :(

Comment: if for some reason you can't use tikz there (doesn't it just use a locally installed tex?) process your tikz in another system (eg overleaf) and get pdf of each picture then include the pdfs via \includegraphics

Comment: @DavidCarlisle it is very nice, I hope it does not get grounded by the US government :)