# \put command unrecognized

Tags: graphics, positioning

I have been trying to use the `\put` command in TeXstudio 4.1.1.  [ `\put(x,y){\input{xxx}}` ], but it says that the command is unrecognized. My preamble does include `\usepackage{graphicx}`. Same thing with `\usepackage{graphics}`. Is there a new version of `\put`, do I need a different package, or something else?

Thanks

Comment: Exactly what is saying `\put` is unrecognized? If it is your editor, note that the editors probably don't support all possible latex commands. `\put` usually lives inside the `picture` envronment and is defined in the kernel, thus no package should be needed.

Comment: `\put` is not from graphicx. It doesn't mean anything if texstudio doesn't recognize it. Try this here as example: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/114847/2388

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to compose a minimal working example.
This one should compile:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{graphics}

\begin{document}
\setlength{\unitlength}{1cm}
\begin{picture}(10,10)
\put(0,5){\includegraphics{example-image-a}}
\end{picture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you.  It was omission on my part,. Forgot to enclose ```\put``` in figure.

Comment: Unrelated, never use the `minimal` class for anything. It is not for public use and certain things aren't set up, so might confuse packages. Use `article` or `standalone` for MWEs

Comment: @Campa. I tried @giglair's code but deleting the `picture` environment so `\put` was in the normal text area. This raised errors about `\raise`. Are you sure that `\put` can be used anywhere? If so, how?

Comment: @PeterWilson My bad. I thought it started with `\leavevmode` but it doesn't, hence the error you observed. I should amend the statement to: It can be used wherever you like *in horizontal mode*.