# What is the picmac package useful for?

Tags: plain-tex, ctan, knuth

I recently found this package on CTAN by Don: https://ctan.org/pkg/picmac

But there does not seem to be any documentation online about it, could someone provide some minimal examples of it?
Apparently it can do some LaTeXy stuff in plain TeX.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a port of latex `picture` mode `\begin{picture} \put...` to plain tex

As seen in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/114783/draw-an-aircraft-with-tikz/114847#114847) LaTeX can use picture mode for technical drawings, and this makes the same available in plain:

[image]

```
\input picmac

\unitlength=1pt

\beginpicture(200,100)(0,0)
\put(30,40){\line(1,0){150}}
\put(30,40){\line(0,1){60}}
\put(30,100){\line(1,0){20}}
\put(50,100){\line(1,-4){10}}
\put(60,60){\line(1,0){100}}
\put(160,60){\line(1,-1){20}}
\put(100,50){\line(0,-1){80}}
\put(130,50){\line(0,-1){80}}
\put(100,-30){\line(1,0){30}}
\put(100,61){\line(0,1){49}}
\put(130,61){\line(0,1){49}}
\put(100,110){\line(1,0){30}}
\endpicture

\bye
```

Comment: That makes sense thank you! Do you know if it's possible to draw curve lines with it?

Comment: @atrst yes it has qbezier curves, not sure if that is identical to the latex quadratic curves, probably is. I would not use that this century though, it is positioning hundreds of `.` to "draw" a curve, which will always look clunky compared to real scalable curves drawn with PostScript or pdf `\special` for which many macros notably tikz or pstricks are available, even in plain

Comment: I see, not the most elegant solution

Comment: @atrst smilarly the lines are not drawn they are made by positioning multiple characters using a custom font with loads of `/` at different slopes. it makes portable dvi with no dependence on dvips or pdftex or any other back end and it was clever (and big) tex code by 1985 standards, but in 2022.....