# Can I use ltxdoc, makeidx, doc and bookmarks? If so, how?

Tags: bookmarks, documentation, makeidx, doc, ltxdoc

Is it possible to use `ltxdoc.cls` with `makeidx` and `bookmark`?

MNWE:

```
\documentclass{ltxdoc}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\makeindex
\begin{document}
\DescribeMacro{\mymacro}\marg{argument}\par
\printindex
\end{document}
```

Following the advice in comments, I then tried

```
makeindex -s gind.ist prawf
```

Here's `makeindex`'s transcript:

```
This is makeindex, version 2.17 [TeX Live 2023] (kpathsea + Thai 
support).
Scanning style file /usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/makeindex/latex/gind.ist.............done (13 attributes redefined, 3 ignored).
Scanning input file prawf.idx...done (0 entries accepted, 1 rejected).
Nothing written in prawf.ind.
Transcript written in prawf.ilg.
```

The log:

```
This is makeindex, version 2.17 [TeX Live 2023] (kpathsea + Thai support).
Scanning style file /usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/makeindex/latex/gind.ist..........
** Input style error (file = /usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/makeindex/latex/gind.ist, line = 75):
   -- Unknown specifier lethead_prefix.
** Input style error (file = /usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/makeindex/latex/gind.ist, line = 76):
   -- Unknown specifier lethead_suffix.
** Input style error (file = /usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/makeindex/latex/gind.ist, line = 77):
   -- Unknown specifier lethead_flag.
...done (13 attributes redefined, 3 ignored).
Scanning input file prawf.idx...
!! Input index error (file = prawf.idx, line = 1):
   -- Extra `|' at position 46 of first argument.
done (0 entries accepted, 1 rejected).
Nothing written in prawf.ind.
Transcript written in prawf.ilg.
```

The raw index file is

```
\indexentry{mymacro=\verb!*+\mymacro+|hdclindex{2}{usage}|hyperpage}{1}
```

Comment: you do not need doc as that is loaded, use a makeindec style using different special characters such as the gind.ist file distributed with doc.

Comment: BTW: TeX Live provides `mkindex` that processes the `.idx` and `.glo` files of a document using (`makeindex` and) `gind.ist` resp. `gglo.ist`.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle `TEXMFHOME=/d makeindex -s gind.ist prawf`? I have to set the file up to use something different, too, I guess. (I don't make indexes often.) Thanks re. the `doc`. I discovered I'm not explicitly loading it in the actual document, but added it for the MNWE. I know `doc` provides indexing macros, but I don't know if I should be using those or not. (I don't have a dtx.)

Comment: ltxdoc is essentially article class plus doc package, so doc is loaded before you specify it,

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Could you suggest what I need to do beside `-s gind.ist`?

Comment: @cfr `Scanning input file ee131.idx...done (0 entries accepted, 1 rejected).
Nothing written in ee131.ind.` hmm not good:-) i may have no time this evening but I'll try to look later

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you. I really appreciate that. I was sure I was doing something stupid, so I'm only half unhappy you don't immediately point out what. And thanks for finding the `r`!

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I also tried with `doc2` because indexing worked OK in June for `prooftrees` and I've not updated TL. With just `doc2` I still get the error, but if I add a bit of `prooftrees.tex` preamble, it works. (I can't apply this to my new document as it is committed to version 3 of `doc`.) Specifically `\renewcommand*\Describe@Macro[1]{\endgroup
  \marginpar{%
    \raggedleft\PrintDescribeMacro{#1}\par
  }%
  \expandafter\prooftrees@index{\macrolabelname}{\protect\verb \protect #1}\@esphack\ignorespaces}
\newcommand*\macrolabelname{macro}
\def\prooftrees@index#1#2{\index{#1s!#2}}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Wondering if you had a chance to look at this or if there's some alternative approach I could try?

Comment: sorry I was on [one of these](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/114783/draw-an-aircraft-with-tikz/114847#114847) will try to look before I get on another

Comment: @DavidCarlisle If I'd known your muse was demanding your attention, I wouldn't have asked ;). It's only that if I don't get this package on CTAN soon, I'll probably lose the courage. Or I'll find another bug :(.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You get a warning in the log:

```
Package hypdoc Warning: hyperref has been loaded before. Check the options!
```

`hypdoc` loads at the end of the preamble `hyperref` with the option `hyperindex=false` to avoid that it interferes but as you already load `hyperref` through the `bookmark` package this no longer works.

Sadly it is not trivial to disentangle 30 years of history and to avoid this loading order problem: currently the `hyperindex` can't be reset after the package.

The easiest currently for you is to load `hypdoc` earlier, before hyperref:

```
\documentclass{ltxdoc}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{hypdoc}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\makeindex
\begin{document}
\DescribeMacro{\mymacro}\marg{argument}\par
\printindex
\end{document}
```

Additionally, as already mentioned in the comments, you must call makeindex with a special style e.g. `-s gind` then you get this

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! I was trying to do completely the wrong thing. I thought I needed `hyperindex`, so I tried to make sure it had that. Then I realised it was enabled anyway, so I thought the problem must be something else.